# Web scraping using Octoparse

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapinghub, ironwebscraper

I have been trying to use Octoparse to scrape data from a particular webpage.
It has a total of 361 pages and 10 data rows on each page (total of 3610 data points). However, what I get is only 3260 data points.

Normally the process works fine and the event log looks like this:

```
[Click to Paginate] Waiting for Ajax to load...
[Click to Paginate] Ajax loaded.    
Executing [Loop Item] variable list
[Loop Item] executing loop item #1
[Extract Data] Data successfully extracted
[Loop Item] executing loop item #2
[Extract Data] Data successfully extracted
[Loop Item] executing loop item #3
Executing [Loop Item] variable list
...

[Loop Item] executing loop item #10
[Extract Data] Data successfully extracted
[Loop Item] executed 10 times, exiting loop now.
Paginate
```

However, I notice that on multiple occasions, the event log shows something like this.

```
[Click to Paginate] Waiting for Ajax to load...
[Click to Paginate] Ajax loaded.  
Executing [Loop Item] variable list
[Loop Item] executing loop item #1
[Loop Item] executed 1 times, exiting loop now.
```

I have tried to adjust different wait time but did not work. Anyone knows how to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!